# App crashes when I call requestImage

Tags: ios, swift, photokit

My app crashes with error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when this method is called:

```
imageManager.requestImage(for: asset!, targetSize: CGSize(width:100,height:100), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: {(image,info) -> Void in})
```

Full code in view did load:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self;
    collectionView.dataSource = self;

    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: nil);
    let asset = fetchResult.firstObject;

    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
    options.isSynchronous = true

    let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager();
    imageManager.requestImage(for: asset!, targetSize: CGSize(width:100,height:100), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: {(image,info) -> Void in
    print("Got image")
    })
}
```

Anyone know what might be causing the error? I think it has something to do with the closure but I'm not sure what is wrong...

here is the method syntax which I am trying to call:

```
func requestImage(for asset: PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode, options: PHImageRequestOptions?, resultHandler: (UIImage?, [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> PHImageRequestID
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the answer has nothing to do with the line of code. I had to go to View then Debug then click view console so I could see the console print the error message telling me to add the key `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` into the Info.plist.

When you are using the photos framework you have to include the key with a reason for wanting to access the camera roll. Once I added this key into the plist everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @James Zaghini answer to the another level.

You also need to check `UIImage` or info is `nil` or not.

```
guard let asset = asset else { return }

let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager();
imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width:100,height:100), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: {(image,info) -> Void in
    if let img = image{
        print("Got Image")
    }
    if let imgInfo = info{
        print("Info")
    }
})
```